# Grub doesn't show up after windows restart but it does after ubuntu restart

Tags: grub, reboot, grub2

I have dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10.
When I try to restart in Ubuntu grub shows up just fine but when I restart in Windows 10 I get a black screen and nothing boots up.
I need to then shut down my PC from the power button leave it off for a while and only then the grub menu shows up again.

Comment: fastboot(?) on? try turning it off.

Comment: I did turn it off. Did not help.

Comment: Possibly any resident software running? Please describe the Windows startup attempt **in more detail**; what happens, when, with which result.